# How to truncate text with an ellipsis in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I can't find a good way to truncate a line of text with an ellipsis, like this:

[image: Screenshot showing truncation with ellipsis]

Is there any way to do this **without** modifying the text itself? I want it to add the ellipsis intelligently – only when characters are being clipped because the text element is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Sketch Truncate Textlines** plugin.

1. Download it via [this](https://github.com/mamuso/sketch-truncate-textlines) link;
2. Install it ( unzip the file and double click on **sketch-truncate-textlines.sketchplugin** );
3. Select your text;
4. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>;
5. Select number of lines that you want displayed;
6. Done. :)

Comment: Hi. We are looking for long answers here on GDSE rather than answers that rely only upon links. Can you please explain what the plugin does, and perhaps even show an example, just in case the link ever dies. Thanks.